# Use xpath to get the url of a image, but it returns messy results

Tags: python, scrapy

When I tried to get the `url` of a image via `xpath @src`
from this link:
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FK8SQDQ/ref=twister_B00WS2T4ZA?_encoding=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FK8SQDQ)

I thought it would return a url 
[html element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rJX4.png)

but it returned a messy result
[messy result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ9eg.png)

Here is the xpath code:

```
url_img ="//div[@id='imgTagWrapperId']/img[@id='landingImage']/@src"

product_title_xpath = "//h1[@id='title']/span[@id='productTitle']/text()"

product_price_xpath = "//tr[@id='priceblock_ourprice_row']/td[@class='a-> span12']/span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()"
```

I can get the title and price except the url of image.

How to get the exact url?

Appreciate you time and help!

Comment: If you look at the document source, you're getting exactly what you're asking for. The `src` for that image is inline data, not a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for `src` attribute of `<img>` tag in source page you will find out you are getting a right output which is that messy result.
By searching further in source you will find a JSON object that contains URL that you want which is in same XPath with attribute `data-a-dynamic-image`.

```py
>>> import json
>>> json_data = json.loads(
...     response.xpath("//div[@id='imgTagWrapperId']/img[@id='landingImage']/@data-a-dynamic-image").get())
>>> list(iter(json_data))[2]
'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51JN-fLvUiL.jpg'
```